# readOGR {rgdal} taking too long to execute

Tags: r, rgdal

I am trying to execute the readOGR function for a shapefile but it is taking way too long to process and I end up killing the process after 20mins or so. Following is the code:

```
country <- readOGR('shapeFiles','gadm28', encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

The execution hangs after printing the following lines:

```
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "shapeFiles", layer: "gadm28"
with 255272 features
It has 61 fields
```

I am working on Windows 7 with 8GB RAM, using RStudio. Any suggestions on what I could change to get it running quick?

Answer (score 1):

How big is your shape?  Some large shape can take forever to load in R.  I think waiting 20 minutes isn't long enough.

My suggestion, call it before lunch, wait.  Then when it succeed, save your object into a RDATA.

```
save(country, file="country.rdata")
```

Loading the RDATA is faster than the shp itself.